# Как работать с спецсимволами в регулярном выражении?

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

Подскажите пожалуйста, как работать с спец символами в регулярном выражением?

вот есть входные данные например :

```
date = '"ld:" asdfghrty1234578\r\n Lab: C4av06ad10rt00q7EqA1\r\n25.06.22'
```

и мне надо получить все после `"LD:" asdfghrty1234578` Но стоит `\r`

Вот мой код:

```
name_match_3 = re.search(r' \\r (\w+)', date.get('ld'))
regular['Trash'] = (name_match_3.group(1) if name_match_3 else None)
```

и он не работает. Ставил "", [] не помогло

Эти значения находятся в списках словарей если вдруг что

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Вы их не экранируете. Обратная косая черта вам в помощь. И <https://habr.com/ru/post/115825/>, например.

Comment: я пробовал, не работает к сожалению

Comment: А зачем вы в регулярке наставили лишних пробелов, которых нет в исходной строке? Если написать регулярку, которая соответствует содержимому строки, например `r'\r\n (.+)'`, то всё отлично работает даже со спецсимволами (и экранирование тут ни при чём)

Comment: @andreymal, экранирование вообще совсем не при чём тут, или просто можно без него обойтись? Я плохо регулярки знаю, но был уверен, что оно как раз для спецсимволов.

Comment: @andreymal, он тольку одну часть взял а дальше перестал

Comment: @Alexey покажите точный пример того, что конкретно вы хотите взять, а то в текущем тексте вопроса не очень понятно

Comment: @Сергей использование сырых `r''` строк в питоне отключает экранирование слэшем, и `\r` интерпретируются как два обычных символа. А дальше уже движок регулярных выражений использует своё собственное экранирование и интерпретирует этот `\r` как символ возврата каретки, благодаря чему регулярка успешно подходит под исходную строку

Comment: Если вы хотите просто пропустить первую строку, то может проще через `split('\\r')` разбить и взять нужные строки. Пока ничего непонятно что же нужно то

Comment: @andreymal, \r\n Lab: C4av06ad10rt00q7EqA1\r\n25.06.22 всю всю лабуду начиная /r

Comment: @Alexey если начиная с `\r` то просто скобочку переставить: `r'(\r\n .+)'`

Comment: @Alexey ах да, чтобы символ переноса строки тоже захватился точкой, нужно ещё специальный флаг добавить `re.search(r'(\r\n .+)', date, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Comment: У строки есть метод splitlines, который практически любые варианты переноса строки поддерживает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrUTh.png. Дальше уже срезом из списка вытаскиваете нужные элементы.

Comment: @andreymal, а если по пути будет еще и \t то это сильно изменит решение ?

Comment: @andreymal, он берет начальные \r\n а дальше не идет и заканчивает \r\n

Comment: @Alexey с флагом DOTALL точка будет захватывать абсолютно все символы, так что видимо не изменит. А что означает «а дальше не идет» непонятно, у меня на показанном вами примере всё идёт до самого конца

Comment: когда ставлю флаг он все в none превращает:
вот данные с Парсинга 
\r\n info\r\n13.06.22 мало тх.
когда без флага то тока делает:
\r\n info\r

Comment: Что такое «он все в none превращает»? Ничего не понятно, покажите [mcve] который демонстрирует нежелательное поведение

Comment: извините, нашел ошибку забыл что питон сильно чувствителен с табуляцией и пробелами. Я поставил пробел и потом флаг

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо вам. И возник вопрос но это не критично а можно ли убрать \r\n чтобы в итоге их не показывал? чтобы данные красивыми были )))

Comment: @Alexey убрать все пробельные символы по краям `строка.strip()` или заменить в середине `строка.replace('\r\n', 'НАФИГ')`

Answer (score 2):

```
date = '"LD:" asdfghrty1234578\r\n Lab: C4av06ad10rt00q7EqA1\r\n25.06.22'
_, dat = date.split('\r\n', 1)
# dat = date.split('\r\n', 1)[1]
print(dat)

Lab: C4av06ad10rt00q7EqA1
25.06.22

dat = date.split('\r\n')[1:]
print('\r\n'.join(dat))

 Lab: C4av06ad10rt00q7EqA1
25.06.22
```

Comment: к сожалению не могу использовать split так как он запишет в словарь значение список

Comment: @Alexey в dat будет просто строка, а не список.

Comment: к сожалению данный вариант не работает с моими данными а данный вопрос он решил

Comment: @Alexey Добавил вариант из списка в строку:)

Comment: @Сергей Ш спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Да такое можно и вообще без регулярок, просто ищем символ `\r` и выводим всё, что от него и дальше:

```py
data = '"ld:" asdfghrty1234578\r\n Lab: C4av06ad10rt00q7EqA1\r\n25.06.22'
print(data[data.find('\r'):])
```

Вывод:

```
 Lab: C4av06ad10rt00q7EqA1
25.06.22
```

Comment: Хотя такое решение я одобряю, формально это всё-таки не отвечает на поставленный в заголовке вопрос (соседний ответ тоже)